# Phabricator: block push if differential revision didn't pass build

Tags: phabricator

I'd like to restrict pushes if any differential revision (which is being built via a herald rule triggering a harbormaster build plan) did not build successfully. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to setup something similar to the answer on this post: [Is there any way to get Phabricator to push diffs to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173784/is-there-any-way-to-get-phabricator-to-push-diffs-to-a-repository/29175806#29175806)

If you are using Jenkins, it is all spelled out for you there.  If, however, you are using a different build system there will be some work required.

The basic idea is that you have to setup your build system as a blocking reviewer (this can be done through the Herald Rules feature) and set up a way for your build system to inform Phabricator that the build has passed.

A word of caution: If your build system is the only blocking reviewer, as soon as the build passes, the code can be landed.  If you want additional reviewers, they too would have to be setup as blocking reviewers.